# How to display date in an input with twig and symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig

I can't store the actual day in my date input type.
When I set up the twig line to get the date, it works perfectly but then when I try to store it in my input it doesn't display it.

```
twig
{#This line provides the day of today#}
{{ "now"|date("d/m/Y") }}
```

```
twig
{#Then this line doesn't changes the value of the input#}
<input type="date" value="{{ "now"|date("d/m/Y") }}" class="form-control" name="date">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is neither a twig nor a symfony problem...

the format for `<input type="date">`'s value is `YYYY-mm-dd`. The display is something different. `<input type="date">` will format depending on user locale and stuff.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date